# How can I set the minimum and maximum value for the TextField?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I set the minimum value of the datetime-local where the user cannot pick the date of yesterday?
I tried setting a min inside the input props and it's not working. Also How can I set a maximum value where the user cannot pick a time between 5pm and 8am?

```
const settingOfDate = (t) => {
  const [deliveryDate, setDeliveryDate] = useState();


  //convert firebase firestore date to Javascript date
  const date = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(deliveryDate));
  const jsDate = date.toDate();
  const locale = jsDate.toLocaleString();

  //get local time zone
  const localTime = new Date();

  return (
    <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <TextField
                id="date"
                label="Delivery Date"
                type="datetime-local"
                inputProps={{
                  min: `${localTime}`,
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setDeliveryDate(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
      </div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_datetime-local_min

Comment: @AnoopJoshi It does work but how can I set the maximum value dynamically? I wanted to set the maximum where date will be the current date and the maximum time will be between 5pm to 8am?

Comment: are you using moment?

Comment: No, just the normal textfield type

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the max date with this format `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS'` , It would be easy if you use moment for formatting the date.

```
 const localTime = new Date();
  const maxDate= moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS')

  return (
    <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <TextField
                max={maxDate}
                id="date"
                label="Delivery Date"
                type="datetime-local"
                inputProps={{
                  min: `${localTime}`,
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setDeliveryDate(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
      </div>
```

Comment: I have installed moment already. However, is there some way where I can restrict the time where you cannot click the hours between 5PM to 8AM?

Comment: I am afraid, if there is any time range option available in  type="datetime-local". You probably need to use some other 3rd party plugin for that.

Comment: do you know any plug ins for that?

Comment: seems like this one has the feature https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-range-picker